Can the POA for a POA of a person act as agent for that third person?
Person "A" appoints person "B" as their power of attorney. Person B appoints person "C" as their power of attorney. Persons A and B both become incapacitated and person B now lacks capacity to act on behalf of person A. Can person C act on behalf of person A in the capacity of power of attorney for person B?

Person "A"s POA will normally specify an alternate if person "B" becomes incapacitated.  It may or may not be person "C".

In the particular case I have in mind, person A’s primary POA is deceased and the alternate has advanced dementia. Person A also has advanced dementia.

I presume these are enduring POA, because normal POA cease on incapacity of the Principal.

You've asked a good question, I only made my comment because person A and C may not know each other, and there is no reason to believe that C would want the responsibility, or would even act in the best interest of A.  A representative for A would likely need to be assigned by the courts.  It may be C, it may not...  I doubt there is any automatic or implied delegation of responsibility.

Person C cannot act as a durable power of attorney agent for Person A simply because Person C was named as durable power of attorney agent for person B who was named as a durable power of attorney agent for Person A.
Designation of a power of attorney agent in a durable power of attorney is personal to the person named and this designation is generally not assignable (unless the durable power of attorney instrument expressly says otherwise).
Instead, a person interested in the well-being of incapacitated Person A would have to apply to a court to be appointed as a guardian and/or conservator for Person A under the laws for who is eligible to be (and has priority to be) appointed as a guardian and/or conservator for Person A.
Side Comments
As noted in a comment, non-durable powers of attorney cease to be effective upon the incapacity of the principal. But the context of the question suggests that this question is really about an estate planning type durable power of attorney.
Also, a duly appointed agent under a power of attorney, like Person B, while having capacity, could employ someone to act as Person B's agent to do a particular task in a non-durable power of attorney -- for example, to pick up a package for Person B or to carry out a stock exchange sale, in furtherance of Person B's actions as durable power of attorney agent for Person A.
The reason for this distinction isn't necessarily well spelled out in case law or statutory law in many states, but is widely understood, and makes intuitive sense in cases as they present themselves.
Basically, the reason for the distinction is that a durable power of attorney agent for an incapacitated person has much wider discretion than an agent under a limited non-durable power of attorney agency to carry out a narrow, well-defined task. The principal in a durable power of attorney is entrusting the durable power of attorney agent with very broad global discretion to act on behalf of the principal and is reposing a great deal of trust in that person. In contrast, a principal under a non-durable limited power of attorney is not putting nearly the same kind of trust in an agent to carry out broad discretionary decisions.

Just to clarify, in the 2nd para “generally not assignable (unless the durable power of attorney instrument expressly says otherwise)” — is it specifically the first PoA document that has to specify this, or both, or either?  I.e. if Alice entrusts PoA to Bob, and Bob entrusts PoA to Carol, is it primarily the Alice–Bob agreement that would determine whether the PoA for Alice can get designated to Carol?

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Possibly jurisdiction-dependent, but the first PoA must specify this arrangement or it will apply the default rule, which is that that agreement terminates with the incapacity of the agent it names. (See for instance RCW 11.125.100(1)(f): "A power of attorney terminates when the agent becomes incapacitated and the power of attorney does not provide for another agent to act.") Confirmatory language in the second PoA wouldn't hurt but isn't statutorily required.

Does this also mean that B, acting as POA for A, cannot appoint C directly as POA for A (unless the power to do so is granted expressly)?  (This is somewhat different from the situation under consideration in the question, which is asking about automatic transitivity in the POA relationship.)

@phoog B, acting as POA for A, cannot appoint C directly as POA for A, although B can appoint C as POA for B to carry out B's duties to A while B is still in office as POA for A (unless the power to do so is granted expressly, which lots of trusts do, and almost no POAs do).

Not in those circumstances
new-south-wales
Under s5 of the Powers of Attorney Act 2003, the incapacity of person B creates a vacancy in the position of attorney for person A. That is, B is no longer A’s attorney so the question of delegation is moot.
More generally, under s45, an attorney’s powers are non-delegatable unless the instrument appointing them says they are. Attorneys can use agents in circumstances where the principal could also use an agent, but they cannot delegate or assign their powers as attorney.
